# Openshift git push error

Tags: openshift-origin

I recently installed an openshift instance with 2 brokers 2 nodes and 3 mongodb/active mq nodes.
I used the openshift origin puppet module and it is mostly working ok.
I can create, move & deploy normal and scalable applications but when I push changes to my gear (using git) I get the following error message:

Failed to report deployment to broker.  This will be corrected on the next git push. Message: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

The push itself is successful:

remote: Git Post-Receive Result: success
remote: Activation status: success
remote: Deployment completed with status: success

But I always get this error message when I push.
I checked the node and broker logs I tried to tcpdump the servers and use wireshark to check the communication between node and broker and I tried to google the error and came up with mostly nothing.
I also went over the deployment guide and checked the installation and everything seems to be in order.

When I:

```
curl https://MyBroker/broker/rest/api
```

I get an api response and not an SSL error:

```
{"api_version":1.7,"data":{"API": {"href":"https://MyBroker/broker/rest/api","method":"GET","optional_params":[] ..
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Keren

Comment: Since this is Openshift Origin I would suggest emailing the dev list here https://lists.openshift.redhat.com/openshiftmm/listinfo